# html escaped characters display issue "&#39" instead of single quote

Tags: java, html, angularjs, spring-boot

When I save data in the java code, I use

```
HtmlUtils.htmlEscape
```

to escape html characters.

However when I get the data back and want to show it in the html (I use Angularjs 1.6). The escaped characters (`&rsquo;`, `&#39;`) are not displayed correctly. How can I make it display <kbd>'</kbd> instead of `&#39;`?

Thanks,
Peter

Comment: Don't escape code when you save it. It causes problems later. Escape just before it hits the layer where those escapes are needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution 1:

You can use the ng-bind-html directive to display it as an html content with all the html entities decoded. Just make sure to include the ngSanitize dependency in your application.

DEMO

JAVASCRIPT

```
angular.module('app', ['ngSanitize'])
  .controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {
       $scope.html = '&quot;12.10 On-Going Submission of &quot;&quot;Made Up&quot;&quot;Samples.&quot;';
   });
```

HTML

```
<body ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <div ng-bind-html="html"></div>
</body>
```

Solution 2: inject $sce in your controller

```
$scope.html = '&quot;12.10 On-Going Submission of &quot;&quot;Made Up&quot;&quot; Samples.&quot;'
$scope.renderHTML = function(html_code)
{
    var decoded = angular.element('<textarea />').html(html_code).text();
    return $sce.trustAsHtml(decoded);
};
```

HTML

```
<div ng-bind-html="renderHTML(html)"></div>
```